# How to remove SAIKU logo when Exporting saiku graph to pdf or png?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, saiku

I tried to export the chart from saiku and in trying to do so saiku logo also comes along with it. How to remove the saiku logo from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only legal way is to obtain a licence